# How to set a range of numbers for textfield in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I want to set a range i.e between $350000 & $800000 for a text field. If the entered number is less than this range then an alert message should pop up. Plz help

Comment: Plz Provide an eg @AnoopVaidya

Comment: Whenever the moves the focus away from the textfield, parse its text as int and check wether or not it is in the desired range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Objective-C using `NSNumberFormatter` you can use like this:

```
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

nf.minimum = @10;
nf.maximum = @20;

NSNumber *a = [nf numberFromString:@"12"];
NSNumber *b = [nf numberFromString:@"22"]; 
//if the number is beyond the range, it will return nil, so in above b is nil
//so the following check will show the log and alert

if (!a || !b) {
    NSLog(@"Either of them is out of range");
    //show the UIAlert here
}
```

**EDIT:**

You should call the above in following scenarios:

1. User enter a value and does some action. In the beginning of the action use the above.
2. Or every time the user enters and moves away from the textfield, then call the above in `textFieldDidEndEditing:` delegate method of `UITextField`.

***Note***: Since your number has `$` prefixed, please make sure you set the currency style in `nf` as well, instead of trimming it.

Comment: I doubt OP knows when to run that code in his case, would you mind including a little information about when to invoke your code?

Comment: @luk2302: Updated, I hope he will be able to implement it  now.

Comment: Worked like a pro :) Thank You @AnoopVaidya

Comment: @Ashu: Added one more note in the answer.

Comment: Yes it was not working before , then i removed the $ from it. It Works now.

Answer (score -1):

Use `- (void) textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView` method to check the `intergerValue` of text and if it doesn't match your requirement show the popup.

If wanna check it on the go use `- (BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text`

```
NSString *finalText = [textView.text stringByAppendingPathComponent:text];
finalText = [finalText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

//enable button
if ([finalText integerValue] < 350000 || [finalText integerValue] > 850000) //do what you wanna do
```

Make sure $ is out of textfield or you remove it before using `integerValue`.

Comment: i dont  want to chk lenght... @rptwsthi

Answer (score -1):

This can be helpfull

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
    {        
      [txt addTarget:self action:@selector(CheckingMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }

-(IBAction)CheckingMethod:(id)sender
   {

   if(txt.text.length>9) {
     //your popupview
   }
    else{
     }
   }
```

Comment: in what way does that help? Please include at least a little bit of explanation - right now it does not get OP anywhere.

Comment: set your textfield sent event value change  (you can set also in your story board ) than you can put your validation in method

Comment: why he should load the view every time he enters in textfield?